# Double summation manipulation

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, summation, arithmetic, combinatorial-proofs

How to prove the equivalence between these two double sums? Probably it is a stupid task, but I cannot solve it.
Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$, prove that for every $\alpha,\beta,s_i\in\mathbb{R}$ it holds
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^j\dfrac{(-1)^is_{2j}\alpha^{2j-2i}\beta^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!(2j-2i)!}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^{k-j-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{j}s_{2i+2j}\alpha^{2i}\beta^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!(2i)!}.
$$
Maybe, beside this, there is the property of double summation $\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^ja_ib_{j-i}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_j\sum_{i=0}^{n-j}b_i$, but I cannot solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a mere change of variable. To solve it, use other variables than $i$ and $j$ on one side, otherwise it's confusing.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to handle the term $s_{2j}$.

Comment: @GiulioBinosi: Setting $k=1$, it seems the left-hand side is $s_0\beta$ whereas the right-hand side gives $-s_0\beta$.

Comment: @epi163sqrt uhm, probably in the right hand side there must be $(-1)^{-j}$, let me check my computations.

Comment: @epi163sqrt yes, you were right. I fixed the question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine. Here is an answer with some additional information. We want to show the following identity is valid:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^j\dfrac{(-1)^is_{2j}\alpha^{2j-2i}\beta^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!(2j-2i)!}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^{k-j-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{j}s_{2i+2j}\alpha^{2i}\beta^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!(2i)!}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We start with the right-hand side of (1) and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}}&\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-j-1}
> \frac{(-1)^js_{2i+2j}\alpha^{2i}\beta^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!(2i)!}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-i-1}\frac{(-1)^is_{2i+2j}\alpha^{2j}\beta^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!(2j)!}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{j=i}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^is_{2j}\alpha^{2j-2i}\beta^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!(2j-2i)!}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq i\leq j\leq k-1}\frac{(-1)^is_{2j}\alpha^{2j-2i}\beta^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!(2j-2i)!}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^{j}\frac{(-1)^is_{2j}\alpha^{2j-2i}\beta^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!(2j-2i)!}}\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we exchange the names of the indices $i\leftrightarrow j$.
- In (3) we shift the index of the inner sum to start with $j=i$.
- In (4) we write the index region more conveniently as preparation for the next step.
- In (5) we exchange inner and outer sum.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is the way to prove it, even if I am not sure about some details.
Let us manipulate the r.h.s. of the equality by substituting $i\to i-j$ and then switching the indexes:
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^{k-j-1}\dfrac{(-1)^js_{2i+2j}\alpha^{2i}\beta^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!(2i)!}&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{i=j}^{k-1}\dfrac{(-1)^js_{2i}\alpha^{2i-2j}\beta^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!(2i-2j)!}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{j=i}^{k-1}\dfrac{(-1)^is_{2j}\alpha^{2j-2i}\beta^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!(2j-2i)!}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^j\dfrac{(-1)^is_{2j}\alpha^{2j-2i}\beta^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!(2j-2i)!},
\end{split}
$$
where last equality follows since if $i>j$, we assume conventionally $(2j-2i)!=\infty$.
This last statement does not convince me totally but I think it works.

Comment: I've added an answer which might be helpful. Note that in the last equality we have $i\leq j$. So there is no reason for any additional assumption.